# ArrayStack - saving pre previous value

Tags: java, stack

How would I `pop()` then `pop()` again and then add the value of first pop the to `top()` value?

`pop(1)` -> `pop(2)` -> `push (1+top())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `pop` gets the topmost value from the stack and *removes* it from the stack. So you would need to do

```
i = pop;
j = pop; 

push(i + top)
```

Example:

```
Operation    Stack
             1
             1
             3

i = pop      1
             3

j = pop      3

push(i+top)  4
             3
```